# git branch -D does not delete local branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've been facing some issues with GIT lately. In my work we have some branches for develop, QA and so... sometimes a branch gets contaminated so we have to reset it. We make it like this:

1. We delete the local branch with `git branch -D develop_branch`
2. We delete the remote branch via gitHub interface.
3. We create a new local branch with `git checkout -b develop_branch`
4. We pull the branch with `git pull origin develop_branch`

In this very moment, the old code comes to our new branch. It may take some time for git to delete the branch? There's a way to be sure that the branch is deleted?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the remote branch is deleted, you still have a copy of it in your `refs/remotes`.  Add `--prune` to `git pull` (or `git fetch`) to automatically delete local remote refs not present in the origin.

1. `git branch -D develop_branch`
2. `git push origin :develop_branch` (or delete remote branch via GitHub interface)
3. `git checkout -b develop_branch`
4. `git pull --prune origin develop_branch`

Answer (score 0):

Check if remote branch is deleted:

```
git branch -r
```

will show all remote branches

You don't need to use github interface to delete a remote branch, instead do:

```
git push origin :develop_branch
```

(Note the colon : before local_branch_name)

And in addition:
after you make a new local branch, push it like this to 'copy' it to remote:

```
git push --set-upstream origin newlocalbranch
```

Comment: out of the scope of the question but a great tip! thank you!